# Request response scenario with the federation plugin enabled

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a general question about the RabbitMQ Federation plugin. Can this plugin handle a Request/Response scenario? I mean doing a request to the upstream server and responding on the downstream server. Is this possible?

I tested this:

1. After configuring the plugin, I do a request to the upstream
   server.
2. The message reaches the downstream server and is being
   consumed there.
3. But when responding from there, I get a
   `EndpointNotFoundException` (masstransit exception).

**More information**

I have federation configured in one direction only (from upstream to downstream).

The exact error message that `RespondAsync` throws on the downstream server is this:

```
MassTransit.Messages Error: 0 : R-FAULT rabbitmq://DOWNSTREAMSERVER:5671/ClusteredRmqQueue N/A ClusteredRmqMessage RabbitMQConsumer.ClusteredRmqConsumer(00:00:42.0309281) The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://UPSTREAMSERVER/bus-RabbitMQPublisher-rnuoyyrtr44jpo8wbdmo78a3y6?durable=false&autodelete=true, MassTransit.EndpointNotFoundException: The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://UPSTREAMSERVER/bus-RabbitMQPublisher-rnuoyyrtr44jpo8wbdmo78a3y6?durable=false&autodelete=true
   at MassTransit.Transports.BusHostCollection`1.GetHost(Uri address)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransportProvider.GetSendTransport(Uri address)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendEndpointProvider.<GetSendEndpoint>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Transports.SendEndpointCache.<GetSendEndpointFromProvider>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Util.Caching.PendingValue`2.<CreateValue>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Transports.SendEndpointCache.<GetSendEndpoint>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.BaseConsumeContext.<GetSendEndpoint>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.BaseConsumeContext.<RespondAsync>d__35`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.ConsumerFactories.DefaultConstructorConsumerFactory`1.<Send>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__4.MoveNext()
MOVE rabbitmq://DOWNSTREAMSERVER:5671/ClusteredRmqQueue N/A rabbitmq://DOWNSTREAMSERVER:5671/ClusteredRmqQueue_error?bind=true&queue=ClusteredRmqQueue_error Fault: The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://UPSTREAMSERVER/bus-RabbitMQPublisher-rnuoyyrtr44jpo8wbdmo78a3y6?durable=false&autodelete=true
Consumed: 0 - 0:14:21:22,0735704. THREAD: 3. Redelivered: True. IsDelivered: False. IsFaulted: False
```